# laravel Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have defined to not use timestamps, but still laravel forces to use timestaps... Im using laravel 5.6.

When I visit page for example - http://mypage/api/videos/21/comments
I get an error - "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `videos_comments` where `videos_comments`.`video_id` = ▶"

app/Providers/VideoComment.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VideoComment extends Model
{
protected $table = 'videos_comments';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = [
  'text', 'userid', 'date'
];
public function videos() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Video', 'id', 'video_id');
}
public function member() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'userid', 'member_id');
}
}
```

app/Providers/Video.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class Video extends Model
{
protected $table = 'videos';
public $timestamps = false;
use Sluggable;

public function sluggable() {
  return [
      'slug' => [
          'source' => 'title'
      ]
    ];
}
public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\VideoComment', 'video_id', 'id');
}
public function member() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'userid', 'member_id');
}
}
```

VideoCommentController.php function

```
   public function index(Video $video) {
    return response()->json($video->comments()->with('member')->latest()->get());
   }
```

Comment: remove `->latest()` from query in `index` function

Comment: Hello @LightScribe VideoCommentController.php file include latest() remove for the query.The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, the result will be ordered by the created_at column.

Comment: @Sohel0415 Mayur Panchal. Thanks that helped for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you use latest() in your query then you have to add created_at in your db table, [read more.](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-get-latest-row-relationship/)

Answer (score 3):

The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, the result will be ordered by the `created_at` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `orderBy` and `first()` instead of `latest()` when you haven't `created_at` column.